# To install and use Django 1.4.1 without sudo access

Tags: linux, python, sudo, django

I want to install [this software](https://github.com/Tietokilta/tenttiarkisto/blob/master/requirements.txt) to a server where I have no sudo access.
They have Django 1.2.x installed there, but the software needs Django 1.4.1. 
The server has the adapter between Python and PostgreSQL database, psycopg2.
Details of the server

```
Linux 3.2.46-grbfs #1 SMP Wed Jun 5 19:48:35 EEST 2013 x86_64
HP DL 360 G7: 2x6-core Xeon @ 3,07 GHz, 144 GB ECC
```

I run the script in Python so I do not need change the script executable

```
python setup.py install
```

and everything goes fine until I get the error on the last line

```
copying django/templatetags/l10n.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/django/templatetags
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.6
copying and adjusting django/bin/django-admin.py -> build/scripts-2.6
changing mode of build/scripts-2.6/django-admin.py from 644 to 755
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django': Permission denied
```

**How can you solve this problem without sudo access?**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html). With that you can create separate Python environments.

Comment: See my extension to your answer below. I tried three weeks ago your proposal but I got stucked in some place. I cannot remember why.

Comment: Try again. If you run into troubles, update your question or post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to Roland's answer.
Yes. I have done this:

```
virtualenv --python=pythonX env
. env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but then I got stucked here.

Answer (score 0):

Use pip to install Django 1.4.1 in a different directory (e.g. `/opt`) and add that to your `$PATH`

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=/opt" Django==1.4.1`